# MongoDb save Date without convert it to UTC on spring boot

Tags: spring, mongodb

I'm trying to add UpdateTime as Date to mongodb repository on spring boot.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class SessionDocumentEntity {
    public String id;
    public int status;
    public LocalDateTime startTime;
    public long duration;
    public LocalDateTime updateTime;
    public String terminationCause;
}
```

I'm using this static func. to set variable value

```
public static LocalDateTime ParseLocalDateTime(String val){
        DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        return LocalDateTime.parse(val,timeFormatter);
    }
```

and i'm using this function like below :

```
        cdrMongoEntity.insertTime = Util.ParseLocalDateTime("2023-07-27 21:43:00");
```

when i set breakpoint to this line insertTime is '2023-07-27T21:43:00' and i expect to see same value when i save through to mongodb. But it comes as 2023-07-27T18:43:00.000+00:00.
How to fix this issue. I'm going to lose my mind. How to get rid of this UTC thing? Additionally, i also try this zonedDateConvert thing like this ;

```
public class ZonedDateTimeReaderConverter implements Converter<Date, ZonedDateTime > {
    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convert(Date date) {
        return date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    }
}
```

```
public class ZonedDateTimeWriteConverter implements Converter<ZonedDateTime, Date> {
    @Override
    public Date convert(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
        return Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant());
    }
}
```

and register them like this but i guess i don't know how to use it when save my model.

```
@Configuration
public class CdrMongoConfig {

    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions() {
        return new MongoCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(new ZonedDateTimeWriteConverter(),
                                                        new ZonedDateTimeReaderConverter()));
    }
}
```

i can provide more info if needed